# Solaris NFS Netgroups?

Tags: solaris, nfs

unfortunately i have to reconfigure a Solaris Dinosaur with an Uptime of over 9 years.
I want to add a few Hosts for an already existing NFS Export on the NFS Server.

```
-               /export/images   sec=sys,ro=toolROimages:shopROweb:shopROapp:checkoutROweb:checkoutROapp:appscluster   ""
```

So it would make the mosts sense to simply extend one of the groups. Apparently i cannot find any definition. These has to be some kind of macros, because some wording of our company is contained.

This oracle doc says these are so called netgroups and can be used for NFS Configs:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36825/gntjt.html

Apparently the file "/etc/netgroup" does not exist. The command Netgroup does neither, only the manpage. But truly, some macros/netgroups must be defined somewhere. i am confused.

Where could be the definition stored? I have read a lot of docs, but none of those seem to apply

```
root@server> uname -a
SunOS server 5.10 Generic_142909-17 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
root@server> uptime;date
  2:09pm  up 3135 day(s),  2:08,  1 user,  load average: 6.37, 5.77, 5.55
Tue Aug 24 14:09:29 CEST 2021
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris, netgroups are defined in either the NIS or LDAP network name services, depending on what's configured in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.  See [the netgroup(5) man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37852/netgroup-5.html) and [the nsswitch.conf(5) man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37852/nsswitch.conf-5.html) for details.